# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in reclassifying raster using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, raster, reclassify

I am trying to reclassify a raster, using arcpy in Python. My code is below

```
from osgeo import gdal
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *


raster_file = 'M:/tgopalakrishna\Data\CONUS_def_001_in_020\CONUS_def_001_in_020.tif'

#Opening the raster file
dataset = gdal.Open(raster_file)
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
print band

#Reading the raster properties
projectionfrom = dataset.GetProjection()
print projectionfrom
geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
print geotransform

block_sizes = band.GetBlockSize()
x_block_size = block_sizes[0]
print x_block_size
y_block_size = block_sizes[1]
print y_block_size

xsize = band.XSize
print xsize
ysize = band.YSize
print ysize

max_value = band.GetMaximum()
print max_value
min_value = band.GetMinimum()
print min_value

stats= band.GetStatistics(0,1) 
print stats # prints min, max, mean and std

# Set local variables
reclassField = "VALUE"
remap = RemapRange([0,999,1])

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

outReclassify = Reclassify(raster_file, reclassField, remap, "NODATA")

outReclassify.save("M:/tgopalakrishna\Outputs\Defended_state/trial.tif")
```

The errors I get are

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "*************trial.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       remap = RemapRange([0,999,1])
>
> File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\ParameterClasses.py", line
>   1160, in **init**
>       _Remap.**init**(self, remapTable)
>
> File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\ParameterClasses.py", line
>   1129, in **init**
>       self.remapTable = [list(record) for record in remapTable]
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

So clearly, there is something wrong with the range of the reclassification. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need double brackets here:

```
remap = RemapRange([[0,999,1]])
```

Because RemapRange expects a list of lists for the remapTable parameter.

Comment: I think RemapRange requires spatial analyst - maybe check out the extension before hitting that method?

Comment: I have checked out the Spatial extension (see towards the end of script)

Comment: Right but do it before you run RemapRange, as scripting is linear.

Comment: DId not help. Same 99999 error.

Comment: Not sure, but what's going on with your crazy forward/back slashes in your paths?  Shouldn't they all be backslashes?

Comment: I have a folder name starting with the letter t, which becomes an escape character when I use \t. So i switched it to /t. Anyway, still get the same 99999 error on using backslashes

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately ended up using the Con tool with syntax

```
outRas= Con(Raster(raster_file)>0 & Raster(raster_file)<999,1,0)
```

Above worked.